# Rx.Observable not been working as expected with using Observable.empty

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

**RxJS version:** 5.5.6

**Code to reproduce:**

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
                  .startWith(0)
                  .flatMap(() => {
                       return Rx.Observable.empty();
                  });

var sub = obs.subscribe(
          (data) => {console.log(data, 1)},
          (err) => {console.log(err, 2)},
          () => {console.log(3)}
);
```

The above code logs nothing

**Expected behavior:** next, complete callback should be triggered

**Actual behavior:** subscribe callbacks not been invoked

**Additional information:**

if we flatMap returns Rx.Observable.of({}), then callbacks get invoked.

according to RxJS documentation
Observable.never() Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer.

Observable.empty() Creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits a complete notification.

```
var obs = Rx.Observable.empty();

var sub = obs.subscribe(
(data) => {
    console.log(data, 1);
},
(err) => {
    console.log(err, 2);
},
() => {
    console.log(3);
},
);
```

//the above code logs 3

If we use Observable.interval() then Observable.empty does not emit a complete notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Observable.empty()` is an observable that complete right away without emits any thing, it is returned from `flatMap`, thus it's `complete` signal is omitted. The observable above is an observable that "never" end (only when the subscription is unsubscribed) and never emits anything.

When you use the `flatMap` operator, your observable use the returned observable of the map function, take the emitted items (not the `complete` signal, error will still buble up though) and emits them. Because your map function returns an `Observable.empty()`, the `flatMap` operator found no items to emit, skip the `complete` signal and returns nothing.

**Difference between `empty` and `never` is**, as in the doc, while both will not emits any item, one will signal that it's completed (`empty`) and one will not (`never`).

Comment: Observable.empty, it does emit changes. If you write the following code 
```
var obs = Rx.Observable.empty();

var sub = obs.subscribe(
(data) => {
   console.log(data, 1);
},
(err) => {
console.log(err, 2);
},
() => {
console.log(3);
},
);

//it would log 3

```

Comment: Yeah, but the `flatMap` operator omitted the `complete` signal so it returns nothing.

Comment: I had updated the description, please take a look.

what is the difference then between .empty and .never?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I've updated the answer, if you found it to answer your question, please kindly mark it as the accepted answer.